# Adding fw rule throw exception

Tags: c#, windows-firewall

I want to add fw rule to block all inbound traffic. If I want to add this rule to firewall app catch `exception HRESULT: 0xD000000D.`
This app worked 2 weeks later but now give me the above exception.

this code I use for add fw rule:

```
public static void CreateRule(string address)
    {
    Type typeFwPolicy2 = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2", false);
    INetFwPolicy2 fwPolicy2 = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFwPolicy2);

    Type typeFWRule = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwRule", false);
    INetFwRule newRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(typeFWRule);

    newRule.Name = "Black List";
    newRule.Description = "Block inbound traffic over TCP";
    newRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_ANY;
    newRule.RemoteAddresses = address;
    newRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
    newRule.Enabled = true;
    newRule.Profiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
    newRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;

    fwPolicy2.Rules.Add(newRule);
}
```

What might be the issue?

Comment: What changed in 2 weeks? and what is the exception?

Comment: I don´t know wath is change, may be some ms update. But about this exception I have not found anything.

Comment: May be I now using a differnet computer, but I have same OS and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same error a couple of times, and i discovered that it caused by invalid ip address. Hackers sometimes sents invalid ip, like dashes or empty text. Try validating ip before storing it.